# Initiating JavaScript call from server side

Tags: javascript, jsf

I was reading [this](http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/JavascriptOpenNewWindow) and about halfway down is a tactic to call a JavaScript function from the server side. Works almost perfectly but I would like to prevent the original page from reloading. Tried to do this with an `<a4j:commandLink>` but then the popup page wasn't appearing at all. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until you post the code you're running, you might not get a specific answer why the `<a4j:commandLink/>` is failing

---

Without any additional libraries however, a hacky way to execute client-side code is to use the `PartialViewContext`. The mechanism is similar to what that tutorial recommends, only that you don't need any utility to achieve the same effect.

```
String javaScriptText = "window.open('"+actionUrl+"', 'popupWindow', 'dependent=yes, menubar=no, toolbar=no');";
FacesContext cxt = FacesContext.getInstance();
PartialViewContext partialCtxt = ctxt.getPartialViewContext();
partialCtxt.getExecuteIds().add(javaScriptText);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I might just end up doing it on the client side instead of on the server side!